# C# TcpClient to netty not always arriving

Tags: java, c#, tcp, netty

Me and a friend are working on a project which requires us to communicate between a C#.NET application and a Java application.
We're using the `TcpClient` and `BinaryWriter` classes on the .NET side of things to send and receive things. We're using code similar to this to send things:

```
byte[] content = //we're getting our content here
Writer.Write(new byte[9]); //this is the BinaryWriter with the NetworkStream of the TcpClient
Writer.Flush();
```

On the Java side of things, we're using netty to handle our networking. To receive the content we send from the .NET side, we add a `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` to the pipeline and use the `channelRead` method to read the content:

```
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object received)
{
    ByteBuf receivedByteBuf = (ByteBuf)received;
    this.bytesRead = receivedByteBuf.readableBytes();
    System.out.println("Received " + this.bytesRead + " bytes.");
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[this.bytesRead];
    receivedByteBuf.markReaderIndex();
    receivedByteBuf.readBytes(buffer);
    receivedByteBuf.resetReaderIndex();
}
```

Now the strange thing is, that when we try sending content, it doesn't always arrive in one piece. Sometimes we only receive all but some bytes we originally sent, which arrive in a new call of `channelRead`. In this example, only 6-8 bytes would arrive. This is very strange, as this only happens when using .NET. We tried sending content using python and everything worked fine and it arrived in one `channelRead` call.

```
import socket
import string, random

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 8888))
s.send(''.join(random.choice(string.lowercase) for x in range(500)))
s.close()
```

Unfortunately, the nature of our project prevents us from changing our Java networking library, so we're stuck with netty.

Did we miss some setting in netty or does this have to do with the nature of the .NET TCP libraries? We would appreciate any help we can get.

Comment: In TCP communications, one sent buffer may result in multiple receive buffers and multiple send may be got in a single receive. In other words, you must either add separators between messages or indicate the message length at beginning of the message.

Comment: @Graffito is there a way to make netty read a minimum amount of bytes?

Comment: There is no real workaround. At best,in case of fixed length L (e.g. 9 bytes), the message length may be omitted and you may loop on ReadBytes, specifying the expected remaining length. For example, you initially read up to 9 bytes, but if you got only 3 bytes, then read up to 6 bytes and so on until the count of received bytes reaches 9.